# Docker enrtypiont not found on django app with alpine python

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine3.17

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

COPY Pipfile /app
COPY Pipfile.lock /app
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system

COPY . /app


USER root
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint-prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint-prod.sh"]
```

This is my entrypoint-prod.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Apply migrations
python manage.py migrate --noinput

# Collect static
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear

# Start the application
gunicorn grayti_backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
```

When I run the image `docker run -it  myapp:latest`, this is the output:

```
exec /app/entrypoint-prod.sh: no such file or directory
```

This error occured only when I moved from `FROM python:3.10` to `FROM python:alpine3.17`

I tried the following but didn't work also:

```
USER root
RUN chmod +x entrypoint-prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint-prod.sh"]
```

Comment: How do you run your container? Are there any volume mappings?

Comment: `docker run -it  myapp:latest`. No there's no volume mapping

Comment: The error only occurs with `python:alpine3.17` base image

Comment: What 'shebang' does your script start with? I.e. the line that starts with `#!`. That points to a shell that needs to exist. It might be `#!/bin/bash` and bash isn't installed on Alpine. You can use `#!/bin/sh` instead.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. i have updated the question for the future. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from [Hans Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) solved my problem. The problem was solved by replacing #!/bin/bash with #!/bin/sh in the `entrypoint-prod.sh` file.